# Rolling back custom field change

Tags: field-update, rollback

Is there a way to get the prior values of a custom field for which history tracking was not setup for and neither was a PRIORVALUE field update field created for it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you backup your data?

Comment: Hi Chale, yeah I have the back-up in SQL. Much of what I am trying to achieve is minimize the amount of manual work that may be involved by going through the SQL route. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you have full sandboxes related to the PRD org and were they refreshed in the recent time, if so you can pull some data as of the refresh date. If not you may be out of luck/contact SF and see what they can do

Comment: @Rao - unfortunately the sandbox is not full copy. I will contact salesforce and see what they say - if that doesn't work, I will use the backup in SQL to restore to an earlier date. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After opening a case with Salesforce and speaking with one of their support, this is what I gathered:

Salesforce can not rollback a field update for which the set history tracking was not setup for (however you can pay $10,000 for data recovery).

But overall, my suggestions as preventative measures are:

1.Set up field tracking history for your frequently or "more important fields". (You have about 40 field limits).
2. If it's a workflow, you can setup up PRIORVALUE field to be updated with the oldvalue of the changed field.
3.Have a backup - e.g full copy sandbox or backup in a db.

Thanks guys!